# Testes unitários com JEST, no Node.Js, sem usar module.exports nos arquivos de código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, testes, testes-de-unidade, jest

Estando os dois arquivos abaixo (`ePar.js` e `ePar.test.js`) em uma mesma pasta, como realizar o teste unitário, com o [JEST](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/), via [Node.Js](https://nodejs.org/en/), da função `ePar` (no arquivo `ePar.js`) **SEM alterar o mesmo**?

Sei que acrescentando `module.exports = ePar;` no final do arquivo `ePar.js` tudo irá funcionar como esperado. **Mas como realizar o teste no mesmo, com o JEST, sem alterá-lo?**

Sem alterá-lo, está retornando o erro:

> TypeError: ePar is not a function

Abaixo o código dos arquivos:

> arquivo: ePar.js

```
var ePar = function(num){ 
    return ((num % 2) === 0) ;
}
```

> arquivo: ePar.test.js

```
var ePar = require('./ePar');

test('Testando função que informa se um número é par ou não', () => {
    let ar_dados = [

        //falsos
        {"input": 1, "valido": false},
        {"input": 3, "valido": false},
        {"input": 5, "valido": false},
        {"input": 15, "valido": false},
        {"input": 5579, "valido": false},

        // verdadeiros
        {"input": 2, "valido": true},
        {"input": 4, "valido": true},
        {"input": 10, "valido": true},
        {"input": 654896, "valido": true}
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < ar_dados.length; i++) {
        expect(ePar(ar_dados[i].input)).toBe(ar_dados[i].valido);
    }
});
```

Desde já, agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Se o teste é unitário e você não está exportando o módulo, qual é a função do módulo em primeiro lugar? Aliás, usar `require` em um arquivo que não exporta nada (um "não-módulo") é algo que realmente não deve funcionar.

Comment: A intenção é simplesmente realizar o teste unitário. Pode ser com ou sem require, apenas executar o teste. Tem alguma ideia de como testar o arquivo ePar.js sem alterá-lo?